# How to extend piped command by contents of variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I would like to extend [this line that calls /usr/bin/mplayer for recording an audio stream](https://github.com/m-ringler/hspiel/blob/ab17daa56431f9249546c626cb65ba3720e27255/record.sh#L220).

The referring script `record.sh` could get called multiple times in parallel and I need to know in which context an error is logged in the error file.

My question is therefore: how do I have to change this line so that in the beginning of each line also the contents of the variable `"$file"` is printed?

```
"$mplayer" $playlist $url $mplayerflags -msglevel all=2 -dumpstream -dumpfile "$file"  >/dev/null 2>>"$errors" <&2 &
```

Example:
Instead of:

```
some arbitrary error message0
some arbitrary error message1
some arbitrary error message2

some arbitrary error message3
some arbitrary error message4
some arbitrary error message5
```

I would like to have:

```
/home/homedir/recordings/filelocation1.mp3 some arbitrary error message0
/home/homedir/recordings/filelocation1.mp3 some arbitrary error message1
/home/homedir/recordings/filelocation1.mp3 some arbitrary error message2

/home/homedir/recordings/filelocation1.mp3 some arbitrary error message3
/home/homedir/recordings/filelocation1.mp3 some arbitrary error message4
/home/homedir/recordings/filelocation1.mp3 some arbitrary error message5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve that by changing the line; just print the file name without a newline before you call mplayer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe to `awk` for instance to prefix each line with the file name:

```
"$mplayer" "${playlist[@]}" "$url" "${mplayerflags[@]}" \
  -msglevel all=2 -dumpstream -dumpfile "$file"  2>&1 > /dev/null |
  F="$file" awk '{print ENVIRON["F"]": "$0}' >> "$errors" &
```

Note:

- I've removed the `<&2` which didn't make sense.
- fixed those unquoted parameter expansions. It seems to me `$playlist` and `$mplayerflags` are meant to be arrays.